# Page refresh on submitting form redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I recently converted my web app project to a single page application, using this script:

```
function AjaxLoadJQuery(pageToLoad){
        var requestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        requestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (requestObject.readyState == 4 && requestObject.status == 200)
            {
                document.open();
                document.write(requestObject.responseText);
                document.close();
            }
            if (requestObject.readyState == 4 && requestObject.status == 404)
            {
                alert('belaj');
            }
        };
        requestObject.open("GET", pageToLoad, true);
        requestObject.send();
    }
```

I use it like this(for example):

```
<li ><a class="djelatnost" onclick="AjaxLoadJQuery('/servis/Struktura/ostalo.html')">NAŠE USLUGE</a></li>
```

I pass it the url of the page I wish to load.

Now I've built a contact form like this:

```
<div id="contact_container" class="container">
        <?php include('C:/wamp/www/servis/Skripte/serverSideValidation.php'); ?>
        <div id="contact_div">
            <form id="contact_form" name="inputForm" method="post" class="formElements">
                Vaše ime<br>
                <input type="text" name="Name" id="cf_name"><span id="nameError"><?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ echo "IMA NESTO JBG"; if(validateName($_POST['Name'])) echo "TESTTEST"; } ?></span><br>
                Vaša e - mail adresa<br>
                <input type="text" id="cf_email" name="Email"><span id="emailError"></span><br>
                Vaša opština<br>
                <input type="text" name="Opstina" id="cf_opstina"><br>
                Vaš grad<br>
                <input type="text" name="Grad" id="cf_grad"><br>
                Vaš broj telefona<br>
                <input type="text" id="cf_brojtel" name="Brojtel"><span id="telefonError"></span><br>
                Predmet poruke<br>
                <select name="Predmet" id="cf_predmet" onchange="setToValueFromCmbBox()">
                    <option value="Ponuda">Ponuda</option>
                    <option value="Kupovina">Kupovina</option>
                    <option value="Pohvala">Pohvala</option>
                    <option value="Zalba">Žalba</option>
                </select><span id="predmetError"></span><br>
                Tip komitenta<br>
                <input name="Tip" type="text" id="cf_tip" disabled><span id="tipError"></span><br>
                Poruka<br>
                <textarea name="Poruka" id="cf_message" >
                </textarea><span id="porukaError"></span><br>
                <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Pošalji" onclick="validateInput();">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see I'm using some spans near input elements to signal eventual errors after server - side validation(I use setCustomValidity() for client side).

The problem is when I press the submit button(with javascript turned off, so I can test .php), the page just reloads and it goes to the page in the address bar(which is the index page), which means everything is changed.

I want to remain on the same page after submit, while at the same time keeping the above used script(for single page app).

Comment: If you are submitting values through ajax, you should change yout button type to button and send the form through your function. When you click in a button of type submit it will send the form data to the page specified on the `action` parameter of the tag `form` if it is missing it you send the data to the same page you are!

Comment: @JorgeCampos If I change the button type then my client side validation doesn't work(setCustomValidity() doesn't popup)

Comment: Actually I now set the action to go directly to the contact page, it works.
If I set it to nothing it goes to the index page because I came to this page through my script. Is there any way I could keep it that way?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! So I see that you answered. If adding the action attribute works, great!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just set an action to point directly to the same page, now it works properly.